# Difficult products options question

Tags: magento-1.9

I thought it was simple but i think it is not.
The case is:
I have simple products that for now have 2 own options to it, both with the same sku.
option 1 is preinstalled and option 2 is not preinstalled.
This worked fine but now i need these simple product in a product bundles.

In product bundles simple products with own options are not selectable. So i thought to make configurable products and make the options "installed and preinstalled" as an atribute an insert these in 2 seperate simple products. This works only problem is that now i need to give them a different sku. And for me it is essential that the sku's stay the same, no matter if they have different options.

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need SKU to be the same for some sort of mapping to your inventory or reporting or something as such.

If that is the case, you can potentially create a custom attribute 'Product Code', in this field you can place the same value for those 2 simple products; hence using this new attribute for reporting or mapping etc. You can then create your own SKU for your products, I suggest something meaningful.